# What is the name of the data inside a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, selector

When using a jQuery selector, what is the name of the data inside the selector.

E.g.

```
$(name)
```

The selector is the `$()`, but what is the official name of the value inside the `$()`?

Thanks

Comment: `$()` it's an alias for [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), it isn't a selector. The selector is what you write inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the W3 Schools, the general form is:

> Basic syntax is: `$(selector).action()`

It seems as though the item inside this statement is the actual selector. The entire statement as a whole (which you called a jQuery selector) is simply a jQuery statement.

More can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp)